# Simple question about the Dirac delta function.

Tags: dirac-delta

I'm a bit confused by the dirac delta function. 
It may sound quite silly, but i'm not quite sure about this.
Let's consider $p(x) = \frac{\delta(x-x_1)}{\delta(x-x_1) + \delta(x-x_2)}$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ is real number and $x_1 \neq x_2$. 

My simple question is then,
can we say $p(x)=1$ for $x=x_1$ and 0 for $x \neq x_1$??


What happen in the case $x_1 = x_2$?
can we say $p(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ for ${}^{\forall} x \in \Re$?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like $0/0$ for $x\neq x_{1}$

Comment: you mean in the case where $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: There's a division by zero problem. How can you divide by a function that's taking the value $0$ at so many points?

Comment: You have to be careful because the Dirac delta "function" is not actually a function, it is a distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). So you cannot work with it as a usual function. For instance, the multiplication of two distributions is not always well defined. This issue is deeper than the "dividing by zero" problem the other comments mention.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can understand your definition of $p(x)$ is as the distribution solution of the equation
$$
(\delta_{x_1} - \delta_{x_2})\,p(x) = \delta_{x_1}
$$
In order to give a meaning to this equation, $p$ has to be continuous in $x_1$ and in $x_2$. Since $\delta_c(x)\, p(x) = \delta_c(x)\, p(c)$
$$
\delta_{x_1}\,p(x_1) - \delta_{x_2}\,p(x_2) = \delta_{x_1}
$$
So, any function $p$ such that $p(x_1)=1$ and $p(x_2)=0$ works.

As a summary,
$$
p(x) = \frac{\delta_{x_1}}{\delta_{x_1} - \delta_{x_2}}
$$
**does not defines a unique function, but any solution of this equation verifies $p(x_1)=1$.**

Comment: (+1) for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a limit representation of the delta function for such purposes. For instance, one can use that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta(x-x_{0})=\lim_{\eta\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\eta}{(x-x_{0})^{2}+\eta^{2}}
\end{eqnarray}
although there are many more limiting cases of functions that reduce to the delta function (see for example the Gaussian case or the $\text{sinc}(x)$ function). Using this representation, you could work out the different limits $\to x_{1,2}^{\pm}$, where $\pm$ means approaching from left or right. The parameter $\eta$ eventually tends to $0$ and you can evaluate the limits.